Nuxt is too big,font awesome too big
When I build my project, my build file is up to 8MB due to FontAwesome. After removing FontAwesome from the project, my build file decreases to a maximum of 500KB. I'm trying to optimize the inclusion of FontAwesome icons in my Nuxt.js 3.8+ project to reduce the build size. Here is the code I am currently using:
import {defineNuxtPlugin} from 'nuxt/app';
import {library, config} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import {fal} from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'
import {far} from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'
import {fas} from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    config.autoA11y = false
    library.add(fal, far, fas); // İhtiyacınız olan ikonları buraya ekleyin
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('FontAwesomeIcon', FontAwesomeIcon);
});
plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/fontawesome.js', mode: 'client' },]

There were solutions in some forums but I didn't find any solution for nuxtjs 3.8+

You're embedding 7.5MB of font icons. They take up space. Are you expecting them to not do so?

"There were solutions in some forums" - what did you try and what did not work? You add ALL icons. Did you check the docs? They give the explanation how it's supposed to be done https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/use-with/vue/add-icons#importing-from-svg-icon-packages

@KenWhite I know that icons take up space, but it's ridiculous that they take up so much space. I'm asking how can I reduce it?

@EstusFlask For vue.js your solution, I use nuxt js 3.8+, so the documentation does exactly what I do. https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/use-with/vue/use-with/#nuxt

@furina The linked example says literally "See other examples for how you
can add other styles or just individual icons". If you're not interested in adding several mbs to the bundle then do what it suggests, add "individual icons", this is what the link above shows. Nuxt is a wrapper around Vue, not something totally different.

@EstusFlask I buy the 100 dollar pro version and I use these icons in more than 100 places in my project and do you expect me to import all the icons one by one? Then what is the reason for me to give money?

@furina I have no expectations in this regard, except that competence cannot be bought. You can't expect a library that is being misused to give you the results you want just because it owes it to you. I'd suggest to read the link above thoroughly, it lists your options. In case you don't want to manage the list in code, there are kits and subsets https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/dig-deeper/subsetting , If you want unused icons to not appear in the project, you need to track the ones that are used in some way, it's as simple as that, no matter if you pay money or not

You're adding entire sets of icons in three separate sizes. Of course they take up a lot of space. Why are you loading entire sets instead of just the ones you're actually going to use? It's the difference between using a small hand-carried basket at the supermarket vs. three full-sized shopping carts. Why are you putting every can/piece/chunk of the entire shelf into your cart instead of just selecting what you want and putting it in the basket?

@EstusFlask In other words, when there is the slightest icon change in the design, I need to add this icon to the project and reBuild the project for this small change.

@furina Yes, that's how it works. You can create a list of currently used ones by processing the project with a regex and extracting the names for library.add(), then keeping it up to date. Or switch to CDN-based FA kits and avoid rebuilds, this is one of the reasons to choose svg/component vs css icons

What you asked about is possible in theory but this requires the explicit support from a bundler via a plugin, and also use icons in a project in a specific way that can be easily analyzed. FA doesn't provide the official way to do this, and there's no reliable third-party solution. Not specific to Nuxt, but Nuxt uses Vite by default as other modern Vue setups, and there's no such thing for Vite, so the common way looks like described in the previous comments. Also see https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/issues/233, this can help https://github.com/GTANAdam/fontawesome-autogen

Next time, consider using the free Iconify solution that supports auto-install and auto-import: https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-icons This is quite a powerful feature with good DX and quite flexible. Fontawesome doesn't add value to most people nowadays, paying for it will not make the entire thing easier to use either as mentioned above.

Maybe it's not a solution for your needs, but I suggest you to use Nuxt icon module and/or Iconify fontawesome.
This ensures that only used icons will be used when you build the project. Sure, it may need a rework in the template for the new icon syntax, but it's way better than importing the whole bag of icons together in the end
